# Model validation fails with Invalid Domain in Constraint, when re-run with the same data, it often works as expected, but still sometimes fail

Tags: python, or-tools

I am recently fighting with

`Invalid domain in constraint : linear { vars: 1950912 vars: 1981835 coeffs: 1 coeffs: 1 domain: 0 domain: 0 domain: 0 domain: 0 }`

that I receive after defining variables, constraints and objective - during the model validation.

When I use the same data and re-run the same code, there is often no longer any issue, but sometimes the issue remains.

I am using `python`, `CP-SAT` solver, I multiply my variables with `1_000_000` and cast them to `Int64`. I use `polars` library for the data and convert to `numpy` before defining variables.

These are some of the versions of the packages I use in my poetry environment:

- `python 3.9.16`
- `ortools 9.6.2534`
- `protobuf 4.22.3` (using env variable `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python`)
- `avro 1.11.1`
- `polars 0.17.5`
- `numpy 1.24.2`
- `fastavro 1.7.0`

I also cannot reproduce it out of the production environment (that e.g. differs from AMD and Intel processors and possibly some other aspects), but has the same version of packages installed through poetry.

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Some randomness in your code most likely.

Validation is deterministic and called first when solving.

Another possibility is different protobuf modules. 9.6 is compiled with proto 4.21.